# Java - how check the index's and check if matrix diamond or not

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I should write a program that checks if the matrix is a matrix diamond.
The numbers paint a diamond is the number zero, all other numbers are not important.
The program checks if Matrix is a diamond or not.
Here's an example:
[image: output]

I tried to write the program but could not.
Can help writing a program, and ideas on how to write it in the most effective.

this waht i write so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter length: ");
    int length = in.nextInt();

    int[][] mat = new int[length][length];

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {
            if(mat[i][length/2]==0){
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

i check the first line but i not successful to check the other lines.

Ideas how to continue?

Comment: We can *help* as soon as you show your current code and explain what is not working. We will not just give you a working solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll change it the next ten minutes

Answer (score 1):

Look at the right example. You're basically going to be performing 4 tests, checking if the diagonal that is `n` cells from the corner is all zero.

If you apply that to the left example, you'd be testing the top-/bottom-/left-/right-most cell twice, but so what. Code will be simple and checking is fast.

So, your task is two-fold:

- Calculate `n`.
- Implement the 4 different tests of diagonals that are `n` from the corners.

I'll leave you to it. Feel free to come back and ask a *new* question if you run into a new problem.